# Hibernate JPA no exception when removing detached object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

### Question

I am writing a unittest for a JPA service, and was expecting to see an `IllegalArgumentException` when calling remove() with a newly created and thus detached entity (see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) for thrown exceptions).
**Have I misunderstood the concept of detached entities or is this a bug in the Hibernate implementation?**

### Example

Sorry about the long example, but I wanted to include everything that was need to reproduce the problem.

TestEntity.java

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String value;

    // Getter and setter omitted
}
```

TestEntityTest.java

```
public class TestEntityTest {
    @Test
    public void testDeletion() {
        final EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager1").createEntityManager();

        final TestEntity entity = new TestEntity();

        // Not expected to be contained
        assertTrue(!entityManager.contains(entity));

        try {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            entityManager.remove(entity);
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            fail("No exception thrown");
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // Expected when removing a detached entity
        }
    }
}
```

META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>org.hibernatetest.TestEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:unit-testing-jpa"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>persistence service</name>
    <groupId>jpa.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TEST RESOURCES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only mistake is that a brand-new entity object is not *detached*, it is *transient*, or *new*. Take a look at [this flow-chart lifecycle diagram](http://onjavadev.com/?p=1096) for more information.

The takeaway here is that there are four phases of the Hibernate lifecycle an object can be in.

- New/Transient objects has no representation in the datastore, and is not associated with any context.
- Managed objects have context and are in the datastore.
- Detached objects are in the datastore, but have been removed from the Hibernate context
- Removed objects are no longer in the datastore (or are marked for removal, at least), but still maintain a connection to the context.

Going by the strict wording of the javadoc, your brand-new object is an entity and it is not detached, so there is no error in the code not throwing an exception.

Comment: Well that changes things, thanks for the answer. I wonder why an exception will only thrown in case of removing a detached object, but at least it seems to work as designed.

Comment: My guess would be, the new object has no underlying representation in the datastore and is not tracked by the context, so removing it is an effective no-op. A detached object, on the other hand, has data in the datastore but is not connected to the persistence context, so removing it is no longer an effective no-op, but it's not connected to the context so it cannot *actually* be removed. Hence the exception.